# Python KIVY: how to select a TextInput without mouse click?

Tags: python, kivy, textinput

I want to make a text input selecter (so that the cursor blinks on it) without clicking on the text input itself but on a button. How to do that easily ?

.py:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class Main(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Main, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def select_textinput(self, instance):
        pass


class GUI(App):

    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(Main())
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GUI().run()
```

.kv:

```
#: kivy 1.10.0

<Main>:
    name: "main_screen"

    TextInput:
        id: ti
        text: "Try to put the cursor here without clicking"

    Button:
        text: "Click here to select the text input !"
        on_press: root.select_textinput(ti)
```

Comment: You have to be specific in your problem, instead you have asked about an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) causing my time to be wasted. Update your question and I will be happy to help you again

Answer (score 0):

Just set the focus to True. But to keep it blinking you have to schedule that function:

```
...
from kivy.clock import Clock
from functools import partial

class Main(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Main, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def select_textinput(self, instance):
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.keep_blinking, instance), .5)

    def keep_blinking(self, instance, *args):
        instance.focus = True

...
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as follow. Please refer to the snippets, example and output for details.

1. Use [*select_all()*](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput.select_all) to select all of the text displayed in the TextInput. *Note: If there is no text then nothing is selected.*
2. Use `cursor = (0, 0)` to set the current cursor position at beginning of text
3. Use `focus = True` to pass focus to TextInput.
4. When TextInput is focused, selection is cancelled. Therefore, we delay the text selection using Clock.schedule_once()
5. Replace *on_press* with *on_release* in kv file because whenever the button click is released, the button has focus.
6. Added optional codes (`focus: True`, `cursor_width: 8`) in kv file

[Text Input » API » Note](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html)

> Selection is cancelled when TextInput is focused. If you need to show selection when TextInput is focused, you should delay (use Clock.schedule) the call to the functions for selecting text (select_all, select_text).

## Snippets

### Python Script

```
def select_textinput(self, instance):
    print("Button Clicked - Select Text")
    instance.cursor = (0, 0)
    instance.focus = True
    Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.select_text(instance, dt=dt), 0.1)

def select_text(self, instance, dt):
    instance.select_all()
```

### kv file

```
Button:
    text: "Click here to select the text input !"
    on_release: root.select_textinput(ti)
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.clock import Clock


class Main(Screen):

    def select_textinput(self, instance):
        print("Button Clicked - Select Text")
        instance.cursor = (0, 0)
        instance.focus = True
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: instance.select_all())


class GUI(App):

    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(Main())
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GUI().run()
```

### gui.kv

```
#: kivy 1.10.0

<Main>:
    name: "main_screen"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        TextInput:
            id: ti
            focus: True
            cursor_width: 8  # Default: 1sp
            text: "Try to put the cursor here without clicking"

        Button:
            text: "Click here to select the text input !"
            on_release: root.select_textinput(ti)
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - App Startup]
[image: Img02 - Cursor Blinking & Text Selected by click of button]